# iOS Set Height of Expanding TableCell with Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, expand

I created a TableView with Expandable cell as [shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6n-c5MqMSuI). In my case the expanded area contains a TextView. My view contains a tag (as label text) and its' meaning (in text view). And things are working fine.

I have come up with a situation where a single tag can have multiple meanings. So I need to show all the meanings. So I got to have that many textview's as many meanings for each tag.

I have added a TableView (with TextView in TableCell) inside the expandable part of the table cell. So can add X number of rows in the expanded table cell with each meaning of the tag in single cell. I want to set the height of TextView, TableView and finally TableViewCell. I tried different ways, but am not able to achieve it. Can you help me achieve it the way I am looking for.

Screen shot of something that I am trying to achieve - 
[image]

**UPDATE :-**

My cellForRowAtIndexPath method where I am trying to set properties :-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Table View TAG = %d  ROW = %d", tableView.tag, indexPath.row);

    // TABLE VIEW IN THE CELL
    if (tableView.tag == 10) {  //  cell.valuesTv
        CannedValueCell *ccell = (CannedValueCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cannedValueCell"];

        if (ccell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CannedValueCell" owner:self options:nil];
            ccell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        // Populate valuesTv
        ccell.valueTextView.text = [valuesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(valueTextViewTapped)];
        [ccell.valueTextView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

        //[ccell.valueTextView sizeToFit];  // Makes no difference 
        // CGRect frame = ccell.valueTextView.frame;
        // frame.size.height = ccell.valueTextView.contentSize.height;
        // ccell.valueTextView.frame = frame;

        NSLog(@"*** TEXTView HEIGHT = %f  C_CELL HEIGHT = %f   ** TV HEIGHT = %f", ccell.valueTextView.frame.size.height, ccell.frame.size.height, cell.valuesTv.frame.size.height );  
        // *** TEXTView HEIGHT = 79.000000  C_CELL HEIGHT = 80.000000   ** TV HEIGHT = 80.000000  
        //  AS SET HEIGHT IN STORY BOARD - NO DIFFERENCE
        return ccell;

    } else {

        //  MAIN TABLE VIEW
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CannedCell";

        cell = (CannedCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CannedCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        // Set datasource and delegate for the cell's TableView
        cell.valuesTv.dataSource = self;
        cell.valuesTv.delegate = self;

        .......
    }
}
```

Table view delegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.cannedTV) {
        if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
            return 150;     //(30 + (80 * valuesArray.count));
        else
            return 30;
        }
        return 30;
    }
}
```

This is what the result is :-

[image]

I tried various things, searched a lot on net, but couldn't find solution for the following :-

1. Set height of Text View as much as the contents of it.
2. The inner table should be completely visible - in all cells full textview should be visible with its complete contents properly. So each cell may have different height.
3. Thus the outer/main table expandable cell should also be accordingly set. - For this I tried (30 + (80 * valuesArray.count));, but the inner table doesn't occupy that much space.
4. How to get which textview is tapped ? When textview is tapped, the method valueTextViewTapped is fired, but yet am not able to find which textview is tapped on. How can I pass the indexPath.row to valueTextViewTapped method, so can find which textview was tapped on ??

Can you please guide me set the height of the components accordingly and achieve the requirements. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A `UITableViewCell` can have its height set dynamically using the table view delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. You can respond to a user selecting the `UITableViewCell` using the table view delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table view and table view controller are very powerful tools.

Based on the information provided, your suggested implementation is satisfactory.

A `UITableViewCell` can have its height set dynamically using the table view delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

You can respond to a user selecting the `UITableViewCell` using the table view delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I have added code of my cellForRow.... Am wondering how to populate the tableview with values array. Can you help me.

Comment: I managed to populate the tableview, but am not able to set the height. Can you have a look at the edited Question and help me if you can.

Comment: All of the cell expansion answers I've found in these forums are responding to a tap but is there are way to expand the cell smoothly on a controlled swipe motion? ie: If the swipe was only 20px in length the cell would have expanded just an extra 20px in height. I want to give the user the ability to control the expansion of the cell.

Comment: Silverstar yours is a new question. Please start a new thread by writing a new question. Reference this Q&A and others as relevant